# nested columns bootstrap 4 align bottom

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a form with bootstrap 4, and I have a problem with align one column to the bottom:

[image: my problem]

And this is my code:

```html
<div class="col-md-3 m-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 d-flex flex-column border border-primary bg-light rounded form-group h-100">
      <h3>text</h3>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="i1">i1</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="i1" id="i1" placeholder="i1" value="223108853">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="i1">i1</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="i1" id="i1" placeholder="i1" value="223108853">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 border border-primary bg-light rounded form-group h-100 col align-self-end">
      <h3>bottom box</h3>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="i1">i1</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="i1" id="i1" placeholder="i1" value="223108853">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="i1">i1</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="i1" id="i1" placeholder="i1" value="223108853">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="i1">i1</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="i1" id="i1" placeholder="i1" value="223108853">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="i1">i1</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="i1" id="i1" placeholder="i1" value="223108853">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rotor82/c7ugmsw8/3/

I'm not sure how to fix it, I tried `align-self-end` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the following element to `margin-bottom: 0` (it's currently set to `15px`), you'll solve your problem.

```
.col-md-3.m-2:nth-of-type(2) .col-12:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[image]

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hxd045kz/)